# Docker can not be installed on CentOS

Tags: docker, centos

I am trying to install docker on machine which is

```
Distributor ID:    CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Release:    6.7
Codename:    Final
```

I followed article https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/#install-from-a-package

I am at the step where is says

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```

And when I run it I get

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
sudo: systemctl: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Docker requires kernel version 3.10 or higher, which Centos 6 doesn't have. You'll have to install Docker on Centos 7. The guide you're following also assumes the use of Centos 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already commented, the later versions of Docker only install on CentOS 7. See the OS requirements section at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/#os-requirements. I believe CentOS 6 uses a SysV init system while CentOS 7 is based on systemd. This is why there is no `systemctl` command on your CentOS 6 system.

Answer (score 0):

Docker 1.7.1 is available on [EPEL](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/) as the [`docker-io`](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/docker-io-1.7.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm) package. After that support for RHEL6 was dropped.